# Building a Data Matrix with #ORACLE SQL, If possible

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle

I have a report that was built in Power Bi and my job wants me to replicate with pure SQL. I don't know if it is feasible. Usually with a report like this I would take it out with SQL and manipulate it with Python. But, for this particular instance I would need to build it with SQL, and I am able to use Javascript, but I am just not as familiar with JS. Here is a snippet of what the report looks like:
[image]

So, if you go down the first column, it would say how many EL kids are IN EL, LTEL, AR-LTEL, etc. Then the second column, how many LTEL kids are EL, LTEL, etc. Is this possible to build out in SQL alone, or should I pull all the data and manipulate it with Jacascript?

Comment: Static pivoting is trivial to do in any SQL dialect. Dynamic pivoting -- when the query does not know in advance the number of columns -- can be done in Oracle using Dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have tables in third-normal form representing people, attributes and the attributes those people possess:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people(
  id  NUMBER
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
      PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE attributes(
  name VARCHAR2(10)
       PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE person_attributes (
  id        REFERENCES people(id),
  attribute REFERENCES attributes(name),
  PRIMARY KEY (id, attribute)
);
```

Then you will have some sample data populating those tables (I don't have your data so I am creating some random data):

```sql
INSERT ALL INTO people (id) VALUES (DEFAULT)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 28483;

INSERT INTO attributes (name)
SELECT 'EL'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LTEL'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AR-LTEL'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RFEP'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GATE'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'FRPM'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Special Ed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'SDC'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'RSP'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'LSH'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Homeless'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Foster'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Military'   FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO person_attributes (id, attribute)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'EL'         FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  8324 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'LTEL'       FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST   336 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'AR-LTEL'    FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  1044 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'RFEP'       FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  2300 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'GATE'       FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST   381 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'FRPM'       FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST 14685 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'Special Ed' FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  3539 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'SDC'        FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST   780 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'RSP'        FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  1188 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'LSH'        FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST     4 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'Homeless'   FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST   598 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'Foster'     FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST    62 ROWS ONLY) UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, 'Military'   FROM people ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE() FETCH FIRST  2304 ROWS ONLY);
```

This will create the correct number of students, attributes and the correct number of relationships between each (so the diagonals in your matrix will be correct) but I do not have your student data so students are just being randomly assigned attributes so the rest of the table will not match your data.

Then you can self-`JOIN` the `person_attributes` table and `PIVOT` to generate your "matrix":

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT p1.attribute,
         p2.attribute AS attr2
  FROM   person_attributes p1
         INNER JOIN person_attributes p2
         ON p1.id = p2.id
)
PIVOT (
  COUNT(*)
  FOR attr2 IN (
    'EL' AS EL,
    'LTEL' AS LTEL,
    'AR-LTEL' AS "AR-LTEL",
    'RFEP' AS RFEP,
    'GATE' AS GATE,
    'FRPM' AS FRPM,
    'Special Ed' AS "Special Ed",
    'SDC' AS SDC,
    'RSP' AS RSP,
    'LSH' AS LSH,
    'Homeless' AS "Homeless",
    'Foster' AS "Foster",
    'Military' AS "Military"
  )
)
ORDER BY DECODE(
           attribute, 
           'EL', 1,
           'LTEL', 2,
           'AR-LTEL', 3,
           'RFEP', 4,
           'GATE', 5,
           'FRPM', 6,
           'Special Ed', 7,
           'SDC', 8,
           'RSP', 9,
           'LSH', 10,
           'Homeless', 11,
           'Foster', 12,
           'Military', 13
         )
```

Which, depending on the randomly generated data, may output:

| ATTRIBUTE | EL | LTEL | AR-LTEL | RFEP | GATE | FRPM | Special Ed | SDC | RSP | LSH | Homeless | Foster | Military |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EL | 8324 | 110 | 311 | 640 | 108 | 4313 | 1041 | 225 | 349 | 0 | 178 | 20 | 662 |
| LTEL | 110 | 336 | 22 | 28 | 6 | 168 | 41 | 6 | 11 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 30 |
| AR-LTEL | 311 | 22 | 1044 | 65 | 15 | 532 | 142 | 27 | 47 | 0 | 15 | 3 | 81 |
| RFEP | 640 | 28 | 65 | 2300 | 26 | 1195 | 278 | 71 | 98 | 0 | 44 | 5 | 185 |
| GATE | 108 | 6 | 15 | 26 | 381 | 198 | 64 | 8 | 20 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 24 |
| FRPM | 4313 | 168 | 532 | 1195 | 198 | 14685 | 1828 | 406 | 614 | 2 | 308 | 36 | 1213 |
| Special Ed | 1041 | 41 | 142 | 278 | 64 | 1828 | 3539 | 102 | 150 | 0 | 55 | 5 | 258 |
| SDC | 225 | 6 | 27 | 71 | 8 | 406 | 102 | 780 | 37 | 0 | 14 | 2 | 80 |
| RSP | 349 | 11 | 47 | 98 | 20 | 614 | 150 | 37 | 1188 | 0 | 22 | 3 | 68 |
| LSH | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Homeless | 178 | 9 | 15 | 44 | 7 | 308 | 55 | 14 | 22 | 0 | 598 | 0 | 45 |
| Foster | 20 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 36 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 62 | 4 |
| Military | 662 | 30 | 81 | 185 | 24 | 1213 | 258 | 80 | 68 | 0 | 45 | 4 | 2304 |

You do not tell us what an LCAP student is so we cannot generate the final lines of the table.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_AlBL6o3)

Comment: Just a note: this is a solution for static pivoting.